# Longest Code Golf Answer Ever

Tags: discussion, code-golf, statistics

An interesting number I failed to find - what's the longest [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) accepted answer ever?
Probably someone with SE scripting skills can figure this out.

More accurate phrasing of my question - I'm looking for the longest answer that:

1. Answers a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) question. Maybe it should be limited to pure code-golf (i.e. no bonuses), but I think not.
2. Is accepted.
3. Is rightfully accepted (if the OP accepted a long answer by mistake, it's not interesting).

The longest I could find is [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6166/3544). It's [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity), which makes it a bit less interesting.

Comment: I think there are some poorly thought-out [tag:restricted-source] challenges admitting Unary answers.

Comment: Are you also interested if no answer was accepted, but there is a winning answer (where the lack of acceptance was not due to any problem with it)? Some challenge authors just don't use the accept tick.

Comment: @feersum are any of those such that the Unary answer would be shorter than any other language?

Comment: @trichoplax I'm not sure; there have definitely been ones where Unary easily wins due to a poor scoring system, but maybe none of those could be considered similary to golf.

Comment: What about non-accepted answers? Any worse than [Worst Code Golf ever](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6836/divide-a-number-by-3-without-using-operators/6855#6855)?

Comment: Fun fact: whitespace answers

Answer (score 17):

On the basis of some data.stackexchange.com hacking, assuming the first line of each answer contains its length followed by *bytes* or *char*, it seems to be https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40698/194 (also [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)) at 8559 bytes.

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/75326/194 is an accepted answer of 10791 bytes, but there are shorter answers.

Excluding [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity), and ignoring some other bad candidates, https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/23508/194 might be a good one: it's 4011, but it does have a comment from its author saying that about 1000 of them are redundant.

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12210/194 is 3710 bytes, but mainly data.

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4479/194 is 3031 bytes.

Honourable mention also for https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/75887/194 at 1915.

Comment: At the first link you linked to, the answer immediately below the linked one is 17,055 bytes.

Comment: @OldBunny2800, there are *much* longer answers if you ditch the second requirement (must be the accepted answer).

Comment: Aw, only honourable mention? I need to up my verbosity :)

Comment: Thanks! That's great. Although I was able to golf your first reference down to 6557 bytes. :-D

Answer (score 0):

Not the longest one, but:

The accepted answer on [12 Days of Christmas Lyrics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4191/12-days-of-christmas-lyrics/4372#4372) uses Brainf**k and has 2,974 bytes.

However, it is also tagged [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity).

Comment: That isn't even close to the longest answer. See Peter's list.