# Maximum code-golf length

Tags: discussion, code-golf, asking-questions

If we have a code-golf question that we have a golfed answer to in, say, Python, how long does that program have to be for it to not be a good idea to ask that question/for that to be code-golf (if there is a cut-off at all)?

Comment: There isn't a limit. We have many challenges which take thousands of bytes in languages like Python.

Comment: However, we do have a guideline that a challenge should not just be a couple of simple challenges tied together. If it's long it needs to not be subdivisible.

Comment: Related: [Longest Code Golf Answer Ever](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9805/46076)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [The Thonnu said](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25807/maximum-code-golf-length#comment80010_25807):

> There isn't a limit. We have many challenges which take thousands of bytes in languages like Python.